# Spring, Morphia and DataAccessException implementation

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, data-access-layer

I'm using Morphia and MongoDB with my Spring application. I see in many of the example projects that many of the service interface methods throw a DataAccessException. From what I can tell, this exception is thrown from various framework classes to simplify exception handling for various implementations of data access.

At this point I'm guessing I should catch any errors thrown by Morphia and throw a DataAccessException from my service implementation. So my question is, should I model this approach with my service implementations that use Morphia? Or perhaps I'm just misunderstanding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This makes sense if you want your business logic to be able to react to specific types of `DataAccessException`, without being dependent on the Morphia/Mongo types.

The easiest way to do this is to write a class which implements `PersistenceExceptionTranslator`, and which knows how to translate the Morphia/Mongo exceptions into `DataAccessException`. Declare this class as a bean, and Spring will automatically ask it to translate the exceptions if your DAO class is annotated with `@Repository`.

However, if your business logic or exception-handling logic doesn't really care *which* exception type is thrown, then there would seem to be little point.

Comment: That makes sense I think. Are you saying that I could centralize the catching of Morphia/Mongo exceptions and translate them into more specific DataAccessException types using PersistenceExceptionTranslator rather than handling them in the service implementations?

Comment: @Matt: Exactly, yes. It's a cross-cutting concern, you don't want to clutter your code with it.